# bundle.js appears to be to large for Github

Tags: git, reactjs, github, webpack-2

I have a simple test React.js app that I have put together, and I'd like to host it on Github.  However when I bundle / compile the app the size of the `bundle.js` file is ~ 4.5MB.  And apparently, Github won't allow files that are this size to be served for `gh-pages`.

Does anyone know the max file size I can make the `bundle.js` in order for it to work on Github?

Second, how could I split the `bundle.js` into smaller sizes so that it works on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `devtool: "source-map"` from the `webpack.config.js` and creating a separate webpack configuration file for production builds did the job.

Comment: You can also change the devtool option to a production [setting](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) instead of removing it completely. For production, I use cheap-module-source-map.